# print IP address with interface name

Tags: shell-script

I want to show the IP address like below

```
lo : 127.0.0.1 
eth0 : 192.168.5.123
eth1 : 192.172.0.212
wlan0 : 10.1.0.124
```

I'm able to print all IP address by `ifconfig | awk '/inet addr/{print substr($2,6)}'`. But it is only printing the IPs. Every system have their own interface names and addresses. So my script has to show their interfaces with respect to IP addresses.

Comment: What OS? An interface can have multiple addresses.

Comment: I do run my script on many OSes(mainly embedded devices like raspberry, intel edison..) @jordanm

Comment: I assume they are all Linux? Do you want interfaces without addresses to be ignored?

Comment: yes. Like I shown above @jordanm.

Comment: what if `eth0` has 5 ip addresses, `eth0:1` has another address, `eth0:extra` has 20 more?  do you want to display IPV6 addresses?

Comment: It's good if it shows @Jasen

Comment: well you're probsably best to start with `ip address show` instead of ifconfig. which is what jordann has done.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following will do what you want:

```
$ ip addr | awk '
/^[0-9]+:/ { 
  sub(/:/,"",$2); iface=$2 } 
/^[[:space:]]*inet / { 
  split($2, a, "/")
  print iface" : "a[1] 
}'
lo : 127.0.0.1
br0 : 10.1.10.12
```

Comment: +1 for using the "iproute2" method instead of ifconfig.

Comment: 1. Only works for IPv4, and 2. `foobar <(command)` is better written as `command | foobar`. But +1 anyway.

Comment: But I'm not getting any thing. If I run with `sh` getting error: `Syntax error: "(" unexpected`. When I run command with bash it's not retuning anything.

Comment: @linux_inside, did you try the command with the | instead: ip addr | awk '...etc....'

Comment: @eewanco, getting same problem

Comment: I don't understand why it is not working. I created a `ip.sh` file. And wrote below lines 
`#!/bin/bash
ip addr | awk '
/^[0-9]+:/ { 
  sub(/:/,"",$2); iface=$2 } 
/^[[:space:]]*inet / { 
  split($2, a, "/")
  print iface" : "a[1] 
}'`
And gave executable permission. When I run `./ip.sh` it's not doing anything

Comment: @linux_inside you can use `set -x` to debug. Perhaps the output of `ip addr` is different on your system.

Comment: See the answer of @Noam Manos to get `ip` to give you machine readable output and get out of this `awk`-wardness...

Answer (score 6):

```
ip -o addr | awk '{split($4, a, "/"); print $2" : "a[1]}'
```

Or if you are not interested in the local addresses:

```
ip -o addr show scope global | awk '{split($4, a, "/"); print $2" : "a[1]}'
```

Comment: +1 for the variant with excluding local addresses.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
ip -o a show | cut -d ' ' -f 2,7
```

> lo 127.0.0.1/8
>
> lo ::1/128
>
> enp0s31f6 10.35.4.166/23
>
> enp0s31f6 2620:52:0:2304:367:c01c:fe74:22ed/64
>
> enp0s31f6 fe80::9a54:7adb:839e:fdb6/64
>
> wlp58s0 10.201.132.132/22
>
> wlp58s0 fe80::fa34:41ff:feb3:a06/64
>
> virbr0 192.168.122.1/24
>
> docker0 172.17.0.1/16

Comment: Why does this only have one upvote? it is the one answer that gets you out of the weeds "-o" ftw!

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
for IF in $(ip link show | awk -F: '$1>0 {print $2}')
do
  echo -n "$IF : "
  ip addr show dev "$IF" | awk '$1=="inet"{print gensub("/.*","","",$2)}' | xargs
done
```

You can run it all on one line if you prefer but I thought it would be marginally easier to understand as a loop.

The `ip link show` delivers the list of interfaces. The `ip addr show dev "$IF"` delivers the list of IP addresses associated with the named interface. The `awk` chops out the IP address for each line that starts with `inet`.

It does not match `inet6` and so will not give you IPv6 addresses. However, if you want to include these you can change the `$1=="inet"` construct to `$1~/^inet/`.

Comment: getting error `lo : awk: line 2: function gensub never defined`

Comment: @linux_inside this solution requires `gawk` as the `awk` implementation.

Comment: @linux_inside if you really want to use vanilla `awk` then this construct will give you identical results: `awk '$1=="inet"{ip=$2; gsub("/.*","",ip); print ip}'`

Answer (score 1):

For only IPv4 addresses, use

```
ip -o addr | awk '{split($4, a, "/"); print $2" : "a[1]}' | grep -v '::'
```

I came up with this because the accepted answer is not convenient to paste into a .bashrc file as an alias.

Typing out such a long command everytime is strenuous.

so i  created an alias in my bashrc file

```
sudo nano ~/.bashrc
```

add this line to the end of the file

```
alias myip="ip -o addr | awk '{split(\$4, a, \"/\"); print \$2\" : \"a[1]}' | grep -v '::'"
```

Save using Ctrl+O then exit using Ctrl+X

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

you might have to prefix sudo for the above command

now you can just give the command "myip" in terminal as shown below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Typing this below, will list all of interfaces which have ips -

```
ip r show|grep " src "|cut -d " " -f 3,12
```

Output:

```
tun0 10.0.0.1
eth0 10.0.0.2
enp1 10.0.0.3
```

bare in mind - it won't pick up interfaces which have no ips assigned to them.

Comment: Welcome to U&L!  More recent versions of `ip` print a different number of spaces between output columns, so this command won't always extract the parts you intended.  There may also be more than one route defined per interface, resulting in duplicates.