# Script to print the interfaces and IP addresses

Tags: networking, scripting, rhel, network-interface, ip-address

I would like to run a script to get all network interfaces and their IP addresses of a standalone PC, such that the command line can print out, for example:

```
<interface1>    <IP address>
```

and so forth
This device is installed with RedHat Enterprise Linux 7.0.
I have tried the following command but it only showed me one interface and the loopback address.
The command was:

> hostname --ip-address

There are 2 network interfaces in this PC, but I could only view the interface for the loopback, not the other interface.
How can I get an output in the following manner?

```
<interface1> <non loopback ip address1>
<interface2> <ip address 2>
```

Answer (score 0):

use [ip](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ip.8.html) command:

```
ip -br addr show
```

as explained below

`-br` Print only basic information in a tabular format for better
              readability

`addr` address object on this device

`show` print information about address object.

Comment: I received the following output from the above command:                       Option  "-br" is unknown, try "ip -help".

Comment: @MightStackier could you post the output of `ip -help` to paste-bin? so I can check out which part of it went wrong.

Comment: :Please see the following: Usage: ip [OPTIONS]OBJECT{COMMAND | help} -force ] -batch filename where OBJECT: = { link | addr | ddrlabel | route | rule | neigh | ntable | tu nel | tuntap | m ddr mroute | mrule | monitor | xfrm | netns | 12tp | tcp_metrics | token }         OPTIONS:= {-V[ersion] | -s[tatistics ] | -d[etails] | -r[esolve] | -h [uman-readable] | -iec | f [amily] { inet | inet6 | ipx | dnet | bridge | link } | -4 | -6 | -I | -D  |-B | -0 |   -l[oops] {maximum-addr-flush-attempts } | o[neline] | -t[i estamp] |

Comment: -b[atch] [filename] | -rc[vbuf] [size] | -n[etns] name | -a [ll] }

Comment: go to https://pastebin.com/, try to create a post and send the link to the post to me, not in this thread.

Comment: I can't find a way to pm you directly hence this is the URL :  https://pastebin.com/9Kyn9i8U

Comment: very unfortunately, your redhat release doesn't support -br keyword, however there're some answers may be helpful at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/182400/print-ip-address-with-interface-name

Comment: I found the solution from one of the code there. Thanks anyway.